# Django need first paragraph

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created model with my posts. file blog/models.py:

```py
import datetime

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

and in db i has this record:

```
<p>First paragraph</p>

<p>Second paragraph</p>

<p>Third paragraph</p>

<p>etc</p>

<p>...</p>
```

How I can get result `First paragraph` ONLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with `BeautifulSoup` and make a property that will return the HTML content of the first paragraph. You first install beautifulsoup with:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

then we can define a property that implements logic to extract the first `<p>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def first_paragraph(self):
        bs = BeautifulSoup(self.content)
        return str(bs.find('p'))
```

Comment: Thank you for help!
I something change code:
`import datetime

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.db import models
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def first_paragraph(self):
        bs = BeautifulSoup(self.content)
        return str(bs.p.string) + '...'`